# What's the difference between "collective spirit" and "collectivism"?

Tags: differences

I think the collectivism is more like a political and social culture, while "collective spirit" can be cooperation within a small group.

Comment: "Collective spirit" is kind of like "team spirit".

Answer (score 0):

"I think the collectivism is more like a political and social culture, " this is correct.

"collective spirit" -> the meaning of this will depend upon the context in which it is used. Are you using "collective" as an adjective or as an attributive noun?

It would be helpful if you gave a complete sentence using the phrase with some context.

“**Collectivism**” is a philosophy of common ownership of assets that works towards the common good.

OED:

> **1. The socialistic theory of the collective ownership or control of all the means of production, and especially of the land, by the whole community or State, i.e. the people collectively, for the benefit of the people as a whole.**
>
> 1880   Sat. Rev. 8 May 587   *By Collectivism is meant that everything is to be done and managed by a society. Railways, mines, forests, and even the soil, are to be worked by associations.*

“**collective spirit**” defines the formal or informal attitude of co-operation of a whole group that accompanies actions and circumstances.

> **collective**, adj.
>
> A. adj.
>
> 1.a. Formed by collection of individual persons or things; constituting a collection; gathered into one; taken as a whole; aggregate, collected. (Opposed to individual, and to distributive:
>
> 1991   Los Angeles Times (Nexis) 27 Aug. f3/1   [he]..explained the movement this way: ‘It's a calling of artists and writers to come together with a collective spirit and a unity of purpose, with a unity of perfection’.
>
> **Spirit** (n)
>
> **17.a. A particular (usually specified) character, disposition, or outlook existing in or animating a person or group of people. In later use often (with modifier) denoting the feeling of common purpose and camaraderie shared by a group; see community spirit, team spirit, etc.**
>
> **b. In adverbial phrases indicating the attitude, disposition, or frame of mind with which something is done, considered, or viewed.**